# (iOS) dispatch_async() vs. NSOperationQueue

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I learned iOS programming thanks to Stanford's CS193p course (on iTunes U) as well as the iOS programming book from Big Nerd Ranch.  In both of those, they recommend using `dispatch_async()`, `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, etc. to handle threading and concurrent operations.  However, at WWDC 2012's session on building concurrent UI, the speaker recommended the use of `NSOperationQueue`.

What are the differences between `dispatch_*()` and `NSOperationQueue`, and is there any reason (technical, performance, stylistic, or otherwise) that I should use one over the other?  Is `NSOperationQueue` just an Objective-C wrapper around `dispatch_async`, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: glasz's answer covers pretty much everything very well, but I have to make a point is who to chose what to use. If you want to perform something asynchronously while staying in the scope, you go with (blocks enables) gcd. But If you have a very well defined task, that is reusable and recurring,  and its fine to go out of scope of the class to execute it (and similar tasks) concurrently. you would create `NSOperations` where you can manage functionality specific to that task properly. This is scalable and beautiful at the same time.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`NSOperation*` classes are the higher level api. They hide GCD's lower level api from you so that you can concentrate on getting the task done.

The rule of thumb is: **Use the api of the highest level first and then degrade based on what you need to accomplish.**

The advantage of this approach is that your code stays most agnostic to the specific implementation the vendor provides. 
In this example, using `NSOperation`, you'll be using Apple's implementation of execution queueing (using GCD). Should Apple ever decide to change the details of implementation behind the scenes they can do so without breaking your application's code.
One such example would be Apple deprecating GCD and using a completely different library (which is unlikely because Apple created GCD and everybody seems to love it).

Regarding the matter i recommend consulting the following resources:

- http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/
- https://cocoasamurai.blogspot.de/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html
- https://cocoasamurai.blogspot.de/2009/09/making-nsoperation-look-like-gcd.html
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue
- [Video: *Advanced NSOperations*, WWDC 2015, Session 226](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/)
- [Sample code: *Advanced NSOperations*, WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/)
- [Video: *Building Responsive and Efficient Apps with GCD*, WWDC 2015, Session 718](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/718/)

Now, regarding your specific questions:

> What are the differences between dispatch_*() and NSOperationQueue, [...]

See above.

> [...] and is there any reason (technical, performance, stylistic, or otherwise) that I should use one over the other?

If the `NSOperation` stuff gets your job done, use it.

> Is NSOperationQueue just an Objective-C wrapper around dispatch_async, or is there more to it than that?

Yes, it basically is. Plus features like operation dependencies, easy start/stop.

### Amendment

To say, use the highest level api first might sound intriguing. Of course, if you need a quick way to run code on a specific thread, you don't want to write a whole lot of boilerplate code which makes the use of lower level C functions perfectly valid:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  do_something();
});
```

**But** consider this:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
  do_something();
}];
```

I'd recommend the latter because most of what you'll write is Objective-C anyway so why not embrace its expressiveness?

Answer (score 12):

NSOperationQueue is much heavier weight than dispatch_async(), it is only based on GCD in a very limited way (essentially it just uses the global dispatch queue to execute its asynchronous operations but otherwise uses no other GCD facilities).

NSOperationQueue does have additional capabilities not provided by GCD, but if you don't need these, using GCD will give you better performance.

Answer (score 10):

They both are doing the same thing but main difference between them is that-
We can cancel the task if we want while using NSOperation whereas if we use GCD, then once we assign the task to queue then we are not able to cancel it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to above answer, the other advantage of NSOperation queue over GCD are

1)  **Dependencies:-**  We can set up a dependency between two NSOperations
the operation will not start until all of its dependencies return true for finished.

2) **State of Operation:-** We can monitor the state of an operation or operation queue. Ready, executing or finished

3) **Max Number of Operation:-**
We can specify the maximum number of queued operations that can run simultaneously