# Taking Too much time for fetch contacts and store in core data issue

Tags: core-data, contacts

I have more than 6000 contacts in my iPad and fetch all contacts as well as store in core data and I have already implemented this functionality in my app but **its taking too much time for fetch and load data so Is there any way to fetch, store data asynchronously or other way**.

So Please give me suggestions or any idea for solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

**//Code for synchronize contacts**

```
- (void)synchronizeContacts
{

if (self.syncStatus)
    {
        //Loading and showing the activity indicator view
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showActivityIndicator:)
                                 toTarget:self
                               withObject:@"Synchronizing contacts..."];
    }

if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
    {
        // First time access has been granted, add the contact
        NSLog(@"First time access has been granted, add the contact");
        [self synchronizeContactsFromContacts];
    });
}
else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{
    // The user has previously given access, add the contact
    NSLog(@"The user has previously given access, add the contact");        
    [self synchronizeContactsFromContacts];
}
else {
    // The user has previously denied access
    // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
    NSLog(@"The user has previously denied access");
}

}

-(void)synchronizeContactsFromContacts
{
    NSMutableArray *phoneContactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *allDeviceContacts=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Do whatever you want here.

ABAddressBookRef iphoneAddress = ABAddressBookCreate();

//read all sources
CFArrayRef sourcesArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(iphoneAddress);
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(sourcesArray); i++)
{
    ABRecordRef iphoneSource = (ABRecordRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sourcesArray, i);
    NSArray *allPersons = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(iphoneAddress, iphoneSource, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
    [allDeviceContacts addObjectsFromArray:allPersons];

    //read all persons
    for(int nameIndex=0; nameIndex<[allPersons count]; nameIndex++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = [allPersons objectAtIndex:nameIndex];

        //person modification date
        CFDateRef lastModifyDate = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonModificationDateProperty);

        NSDate *lastSyncDate = [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] getLastContactSynchedDate];

        if(lastSyncDate)
        {
            NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [lastSyncDate timeIntervalSinceDate: (NSDate*)lastModifyDate] * -1000.0;
            if(timeInterval <= 0) //skip if this conatct is not modified
            {
                if(lastModifyDate)
                    CFRelease(lastModifyDate);

                continue;
            }
        }
        if(lastModifyDate)
            CFRelease(lastModifyDate);


        NSString *nullValue = @"";
        NSNumber *zeroValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

        NSMutableDictionary *companyAddress = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               zeroValue, @"personUId",
                                               zeroValue, KEYCONTACTS_CONTACTID,
                                               zeroValue, KEYCONTACTS_ID,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_NAME,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_LAST_NAME,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_STREET,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_CITY,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_STATE,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_ZIP,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_COUNTRY,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_PHONE,
                                               nullValue, KEYCONTACTS_EMAIL,
                                               nullValue, @"company_Name",
                                               nullValue, @"website",
                                               nullValue, @"mobile",
                                               nil];

        NSString *fName = @"";
        //NSString *mName = @"";
        NSString *lName = @"";
        // NSString *profileName = @"";
        NSString *profileCompanyText = @"";



        //get name
        fName=(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        //mName=(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty);
        lName=(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

        //profileName = [self concatnateContactName:fName middleName:mName andLastName:lName];
        [companyAddress setValue:fName forKey:KEYCONTACTS_NAME];
        [companyAddress setValue:lName forKey:KEYCONTACTS_LAST_NAME];

        [fName release];
        //[mName release];
        [lName release];

        [companyAddress setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)] forKey:@"personUId"];
        //NSLog(@"%d",ABRecordGetRecordID(person));

        //for mapping org name to comp name
        CFTypeRef profileCompany = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonOrganizationProperty );
        if(profileCompany)
        {
            profileCompanyText  = (NSString*)profileCompany;
            [companyAddress setValue:profileCompanyText forKey:@"company_Name"];
            CFRelease(profileCompany);
        }

        //get email id
        ABMutableMultiValueRef multiValue = nil;
        if(multiValue)
        {
            CFRelease(multiValue);
            multiValue =nil;
        }
        multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue) > 0)
        {
            CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, 0);
            [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)dict forKey:KEYCONTACTS_EMAIL];
            CFRelease(dict);
        }

        if(multiValue)
        {
            CFRelease(multiValue);
            multiValue =nil;
        }


        //get URL
        multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue) > 0)
        {
            CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, 0);
            [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)dict forKey:@"website"];
            CFRelease(dict);
        }

        if(multiValue)
        {
            CFRelease(multiValue);
            multiValue =nil;
        }

        //to get address from iphone contacts
        multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue) > 0)
        {
            CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, 0);
            CFStringRef street = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
            CFStringRef city = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
            CFStringRef state = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey);
            CFStringRef zip = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey);
            CFStringRef country = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey);
            CFRelease(dict);

            [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)street forKey:KEYCONTACTS_STREET];
            [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)city forKey:KEYCONTACTS_CITY];
            [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)state forKey:KEYCONTACTS_STATE];
            [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)zip forKey:KEYCONTACTS_ZIP];
            [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)country forKey:KEYCONTACTS_COUNTRY];
        }
        if(multiValue)
        {
            CFRelease(multiValue);
            multiValue =nil;
        }



        //get contact number
        multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        CFStringRef phoneNumber;
        NSString* mobileLabel;
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue) > 0)
        {
            for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue); i++)
            {
                mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValue, i);
                if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Mobile>!$_"]) {
                    phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, i);
                    [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)phoneNumber forKey:@"mobile"];
                    //NSLog(@"1=%@",phoneNumber);
                    CFRelease(phoneNumber);
                }
                else if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"]) {
                    phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, i);
                    [companyAddress setValue:(NSString*)phoneNumber forKey:KEYCONTACTS_PHONE];
                    //NSLog(@"2=%@",phoneNumber);
                    CFRelease(phoneNumber);
                }
                [mobileLabel release];
            }
        }
        if(multiValue)
        {
            CFRelease(multiValue);
            multiValue =nil;
        }

        [phoneContactsArray addObject:companyAddress];
    }

    [allPersons release];

}

CFRelease(sourcesArray);

CFRelease(iphoneAddress);
iphoneAddress=nil;

//delete key contact from app(deleated from native app)
BOOL deleteStatus=YES;
NSArray *allKeyContactArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getAllSyncContacts]];
for(int m=0;m<[allKeyContactArray count];m++){
    int devKeyContactId=[[[allKeyContactArray objectAtIndex:m]devConatctId]intValue];

    deleteStatus=YES;
    for(int n=0;n<[allDeviceContacts count];n++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = [allDeviceContacts objectAtIndex:n];
        int personId=ABRecordGetRecordID(person);

        if(personId==devKeyContactId)
        {
            deleteStatus=NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(deleteStatus==YES)
    {
        //delete key contact
        NSString *deviceId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",devKeyContactId];
        NSArray *syncContactArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getSyncContactsDetailsByDevId:deviceId]];

        if([syncContactArray count]>0)
        {
            int contactId=[[[syncContactArray objectAtIndex:0]appContactId]intValue];

            [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteSyncContacts:contactId];
            [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteKeyContact:contactId];
        }
        [syncContactArray release];
    }

}
[allKeyContactArray release];



//delete company from app(deleated from native app)
//deleteStatus=YES;
NSArray *allCompanyArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getAllSyncCompanies]];
for(int m=0;m<[allCompanyArray count];m++)
{
    int devKeyContactId=[[[allCompanyArray objectAtIndex:m]devCompanyId]intValue];

    deleteStatus=YES;
    for(int n=0;n<[allDeviceContacts count];n++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = [allDeviceContacts objectAtIndex:n];
        int personId=ABRecordGetRecordID(person);

        if(personId==devKeyContactId)
        {
            deleteStatus=NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(deleteStatus==YES)
    {
        //delete contact
        NSString *deviceId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",devKeyContactId];
        NSArray *syncCompanyArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getSyncCompanyDetailsByDevId:deviceId]];

        if([syncCompanyArray count]>0)
        {
            int companyId=[[[syncCompanyArray objectAtIndex:0] appCompanyId]intValue];

            NSString *companyName = nil;
            NSArray *companyArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getContactUsingContactId:companyId]];
            if([companyArray count] > 0)
            {
                Contacts *tempContact=[companyArray objectAtIndex:0];
                companyName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempContact.companyName];
            }
            [companyArray release];

            //delete company
            [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteSyncCompanyByAppId:companyId];
            [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteCompanyById:companyId];


            //check this company has key contact then create company  to app
            NSArray *keyContactOfCompany=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getKeyContactsFromContact:[NSNumber numberWithInt:companyId] searchKey:@"*"]];
            if([keyContactOfCompany count]>0){
                NSString *nullValue = @"";
                NSNumber *zeroValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

                NSDictionary *company = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         zeroValue, CONTACTS_ID,
                                         nullValue, CONTACTS_COMPANYNAME,
                                         nullValue, CONTACTS_STREET,
                                         nullValue, CONTACTS_STATE,
                                         nullValue, CONTACTS_CITY,
                                         nullValue, CONTACTS_ZIP,
                                         nullValue, CONTACTS_COUNTRY,
                                         nullValue, CONTACTS_PHONE,
                                         nullValue, CONTACTS_WEBSITE,
                                         nil];

                [company setValue:companyName forKey:CONTACTS_COMPANYNAME];
                [company setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:companyId] forKey:CONTACTS_ID];
                [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addNewCompanyToApp:company];
            }
            [keyContactOfCompany release];
        }
        [syncCompanyArray release];
    }

}
[allCompanyArray release];



[allDeviceContacts release];



//sort the objects(due to get company first)
NSString *descriptor = KEYCONTACTS_NAME;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:descriptor ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [phoneContactsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[phoneContactsArray removeAllObjects];
[phoneContactsArray addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
[sortDescriptor release];


//keep old company references
NSArray *syncContacts=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getAllSyncCompanyDetails]];
for(int k=0;k<[syncContacts count];k++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *syncCompany = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [syncCompany setValue:[[syncContacts objectAtIndex:k]appCompanyId] forKey:@"appId"];
    [syncCompany setValue:[[syncContacts objectAtIndex:k]devCompanyId] forKey:@"devId"];
    [oldSyncCompanies addObject:syncCompany];
    [syncCompany release];
}
[syncContacts release];


//delete all key contacts
//[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteAllKeyContacts];
//[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteAllSyncContacts];


//delete all contacts
//[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteAllCompany];
//[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteAllSyncCompany];


//delete modified key contact from app
for(int p=0;p<[phoneContactsArray count];p++)
{
    NSString *deviceId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[phoneContactsArray objectAtIndex:p]valueForKey:@"personUId"]intValue]];
    NSArray *syncContactArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getSyncContactsDetailsByDevId:deviceId]];

    if([syncContactArray count]>0)
    {
        int contactId=[[[syncContactArray objectAtIndex:0]appContactId]intValue];

        [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteSyncContacts:contactId];
        [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteKeyContact:contactId];
    }
    [syncContactArray release];
}

//delete modified company from app
for(int p=0;p<[phoneContactsArray count];p++)
{
    NSString *deviceId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[phoneContactsArray objectAtIndex:p]valueForKey:@"personUId"]intValue]];
    NSArray *syncCompanyArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]getSyncCompanyDetailsByDevId:deviceId]];

    if([syncCompanyArray count]>0)
    {
        int companyId=[[[syncCompanyArray objectAtIndex:0] appCompanyId]intValue];

        [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteSyncCompanyByAppId:companyId];
        [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]deleteCompanyById:companyId];
    }
    [syncCompanyArray release];
}

//----------------> phone to app Synchornization <----------------//
for(int n=0;n<[phoneContactsArray count];n++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *phoneContact = [phoneContactsArray objectAtIndex:n];
    NSString *companyName = (NSString*)[phoneContact valueForKey:@"company_Name"];
    NSString *personName = (NSString*)[phoneContact valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_NAME];

    if(!(companyName == NULL) && !([companyName isEqualToString:@""]) && !([trimmedText(companyName) length] == 0))
    {

        if(!(personName == NULL) && !([personName isEqualToString:@""]) && !([trimmedText(personName) length] == 0))
        {
            NSArray *allCompanyArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] searchContact:companyName]];
            //add key contact to existing company
            if([allCompanyArray count]!=0)
            {
                for(Contacts *appContact in allCompanyArray)
                {
                    NSInteger newContactId = [PFCommon getNewKeyContactId];
                    [phoneContact setValue:appContact.contactId  forKey:KEYCONTACTS_CONTACTID];
                    [phoneContact setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newContactId] forKey:KEYCONTACTS_ID];

                    [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addKeyContact:phoneContact];
                    [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addSynchedContacts:newContactId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[phoneContact valueForKey:@"personUId"] intValue]]];
                }
            }
            //create company and add key contact
            else
            {
                [self createNewCompany:phoneContact];
                NSArray *aCompany=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] searchContact:companyName]];

                if([aCompany count]>0)
                {
                    Contacts *newContact= [aCompany objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSNumber *contactId=newContact.contactId;
                    NSInteger newKeyContactId = [PFCommon getNewKeyContactId];

                    [phoneContact setValue:contactId  forKey:KEYCONTACTS_CONTACTID];
                    [phoneContact setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newKeyContactId] forKey:KEYCONTACTS_ID];

                    [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addKeyContact:phoneContact];
                    [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addSynchedContacts:newKeyContactId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[phoneContact valueForKey:@"personUId"] intValue]]];
                }
                [aCompany release];

            }
            [allCompanyArray release];

        }
        else{
            NSArray *allCompanyArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] searchContact:companyName]];
            //check company existing if existing discard this contact
            if([allCompanyArray count]!=0)
            {}
            //create only a company
            else
            {
                [self createNewCompany:phoneContact];
            }
            [allCompanyArray release];
        }
    }
    //if company field is null
    else
    {
        NSArray *uncategoryCompany=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] searchContact:@"Uncategorized"]];
        if([uncategoryCompany count]>0)
        {}
        else
        {
            [self createNewCompany:phoneContact];
            [uncategoryCompany release];
            uncategoryCompany=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] searchContact:@"Uncategorized"]];
        }


        //add new uncategorized key contacts
        NSInteger newContactId = [PFCommon getNewKeyContactId];

        [phoneContact setValue:(id)[[uncategoryCompany objectAtIndex:0]contactId] forKey:KEYCONTACTS_CONTACTID];
        [phoneContact setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newContactId] forKey:KEYCONTACTS_ID];
        [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addKeyContact:phoneContact];

        [[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addSynchedContacts:newContactId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[phoneContact valueForKey:@"personUId"] intValue]]];


        [uncategoryCompany release];
    }
}

[phoneContactsArray release];
phoneContactsArray = nil;

//adds the last synched contact date
[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] addLastContactSynchedDate:[PFCommon getContactSyncId] :[NSDate date]];

[PFCommon setContactSyncStatus:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(hideActivityIndicatorView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];

}


- (void)createNewCompany:(NSMutableDictionary*)aCompany
```

{
    NSString *nullValue = @"";
    NSNumber *zeroValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

```
NSDictionary *company = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         zeroValue, CONTACTS_ID,
                         nullValue, CONTACTS_COMPANYNAME,
                         nullValue, CONTACTS_STREET,
                         nullValue, CONTACTS_STATE,
                         nullValue, CONTACTS_CITY,
                         nullValue, CONTACTS_ZIP,
                         nullValue, CONTACTS_COUNTRY,
                         nullValue, CONTACTS_PHONE,
                         nullValue, CONTACTS_WEBSITE,
                         nil];

NSString *companyName = (NSString*)[aCompany valueForKey:@"company_Name"];
NSString * streetName = (NSString*)[aCompany valueForKey:@"street"];
NSLog(@"companyName  %@",companyName);

//check the company is already added then keep old id
NSInteger contactId=-1;
for(int i=0;i<[oldSyncCompanies count];i++)
{

    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict=[oldSyncCompanies objectAtIndex:i];
    int oldDevId=[[tempDict valueForKey:@"devId"]intValue];
    int newDevId=[[aCompany valueForKey:@"personUId"]intValue];

    if(oldDevId==newDevId)
        contactId=[[tempDict valueForKey:@"appId"] intValue];
}

if(contactId==-1)
    contactId=[PFCommon getNewContactId];

if((companyName == NULL) || ([companyName isEqualToString:@""]) || ([trimmedText(companyName) length] == 0))
{
    [company setValue:@"Uncategorized" forKey:CONTACTS_COMPANYNAME];
    [company setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1] forKey:CONTACTS_ID];
    contactId=-1;
}
else
{
    [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:@"company_Name"] forKey:CONTACTS_COMPANYNAME];
    [company setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:contactId] forKey:CONTACTS_ID];
    //we added due to display company details/address Nikunj
    [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_STREET] forKey:CONTACTS_STREET];
    [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_CITY] forKey:CONTACTS_CITY];
    [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_STATE] forKey:CONTACTS_STATE];
    [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_ZIP] forKey:CONTACTS_ZIP];
    [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_COUNTRY] forKey:CONTACTS_COUNTRY];
    [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_PHONE] forKey:CONTACTS_PHONE];
    [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:@"website"] forKey:CONTACTS_WEBSITE];

    NSString *personName = (NSString*)[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_NAME];
    //NSLog(@"personName %@",personName);
    if((personName == NULL) || ([personName isEqualToString:@""]) || ([trimmedText(personName) length] == 0))
    {
        [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_STREET] forKey:CONTACTS_STREET];
        [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_CITY] forKey:CONTACTS_CITY];
        [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_STATE] forKey:CONTACTS_STATE];
        [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_ZIP] forKey:CONTACTS_ZIP];
        [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_COUNTRY] forKey:CONTACTS_COUNTRY];
        [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:KEYCONTACTS_PHONE] forKey:CONTACTS_PHONE];
        [company setValue:[aCompany valueForKey:@"website"] forKey:CONTACTS_WEBSITE];
    }
}

[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addSynchedCompany:contactId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[aCompany valueForKey:@"personUId"] intValue]]];
[[PFCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController]addNewCompanyToApp:company];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To improve the performance of your app you should really batch your fetches to the store. This means that when reading the data from the database you only load a certain amount of entities for each fetch and not all of them at once. This is really easy to do: you just have to use `-[NSFetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:]` to have the number of entities you pass to the method to be retrieved with each fetch. If you use NSFetchedResultsController to display your contacts in a UITableView, it will automatically load new entities as the user scrolls through the table.

To save the data, you just have to do it in a background thread.

Comment: Please give me code for get contacts and store in database in background if u have

Answer (score 1):

Without wading through the wall of code above, some generic tips:

1. Use Instruments to work out where the time is being spent. Your code has several sections, perhaps the issue can be narrowed down? Then apply more brainpower/caching/drive-by-table to that section.
2. Check you are using a SQLite store, not an XML or binary store.
3. Is this something that can go to a background thread, so your UI isn't affected?

Comment: No nothing, I cant do anything in background thread so please give me idea how can I do for that?

Comment: There are several ways to invoke code on a background thread. GCD, NSOperationQueue, ... Have a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676629/ios-dispatch-async-vs-nsoperationqueue.